# How to use defaultdict to create a dictionary with a lambda function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, lambda, defaultdict

I am trying to create a dictionary with a lambda function which can conditionally insert a value based on the 2nd term in the key.

```
Example:
wts = defaultdict(lambda x: if x[1] == somevalue then 1 else 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) in Python looks like:

```
then_expr if condition else else_expr
```

In your example:

```
wts = defaultdict(lambda x: 1 if x[1] == somevalue else 0)
```

As khelwood pointed out in the comments, the factory function for a `defaultdict` does not take arguments. You have to override [`dict.__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) directly:

```
class WTS(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return 1 if key[1] == somevalue else 0

wts = WTS()
```

Or more readable:

```
class WTS(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        if key[1] == somevalue:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

Comment: The factory function for a `defaultdict` has to take zero arguments. So that's not going to work.

Comment: How do I call it for key = (A,somevalue)?